# How to access print button by Selenium webdriver when it is inside shadow-root?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to provide some address keys to a page to get redirected to another page from where the info can be downloaded as a pdf option.

Code:

```
def appriaser():
    driver.get("https://web.bcpa.net/BcpaClient/#/Record-Search")
    search_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'txtField')))
    search_box.send_keys(address)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    search_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'searchButton')
    search_button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    # Close Pop-Up
    close_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'closeCross')
    close_button.click()
    # Print the pdf
    pdf_appraiser = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hideRecInfoTab"]/div[1]/div/div[12]')))
    pdf_appraiser.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    print_window = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(print_window[-1])
    url = driver.current_url
    print(url)
    driver.execute_script('window.print();')
    download_appraise_pdf = driver.execute_script(
            "return document.querySelector('print-preview-app')"
            ".shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-sidebar')"
            ".shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-button-strip')"
            ".shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-button.action-button')"
        )
    download_appraise_pdf.click()
```

I have checked to see that the driver is shifting to the correct url and after studying a little about the shadow-root I saw that this is one of the ways it can be interacted with.
Getting the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 74, in <module>
    appriaser()
  File ".\test.py", line 68, in appriaser
    "return document.querySelector('print-preview-app')"
  File "D:\Python Projects\Title Search\titlesearch\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 405, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]
  File "D:\Python Projects\Title Search\titlesearch\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python Projects\Title Search\titlesearch\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 
229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.129)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CD47AD02+56930]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD3EF602]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD2A42E5]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD2A9261]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD2AB9FD]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD328E57]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD30BC9A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD3281E2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD30BA43]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD2DD438]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD2DE4D1]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CD7F6F8D+3711213]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CD84865F+4044735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CD519736+706710]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD3FB8DF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD3F6AC4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD3F6C1C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CD3E68D4]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFD02F37344+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFD03F226B1+33]
```

Can anyone help? Am I doing anything wrong to get the output?
Address info for testing: address = "2216 NW 6 PL FORT LAUDERDALE"

Edit 1: Copied the JS Path and pasting it:

```
document.querySelector("body > print-preview-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#sidebar").shadowRoot.querySelector("print-preview-button-strip").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > cr-button.action-button")
```

Also have used it and still getting the same error. Checked it against the Console from Dev Tools.

Comment: @undetected-selenium could you help regarding this?